# Algorithm for Uneven Product allocation in Multiple Warehouses with PHP

Tags: algorithms, php

I have a script which returns the ID's of the warehouses (4,1,2,10,9) in order how close they are to the customer.

`$warehouse_rank = array('0'=>4,'1'=>1, '2'=>2, '3'=>10, '4'=>9);`

When I lookup a product from the database, I return a breakdown of which warehouses have it in stock and the quantity. Like so:

```
$product_breakdown = array(
    'storage'=>array(
        '10001'=>array(
            'total_stock'=>89,
            'breakdown'=>array(
                '4'=>0,
                '1'=>89,
                '2'=>0,
                '10'=>0,
                '9'=>0
            )
        )
    )
);
```

`10001 is the product ID in this case.`

I made this loop to determine which warehouse has the desired quantity, so then I can order it:

```
foreach ($warehouse_rank as $key => $warehouse_id){
    if($product_breakdown['storage'][$product_id['output']]['breakdown'][$warehouse_id] >= $posted->order->quantity) {
    }
}
```

However the problem is this will only detect when the requested quantity is available as whole in the warehouse.

I cannot wrap my head around how to go about when the requested quantity is spread out in multiple warehouses.

---

**For example:**

They request 20 pieces.

And the distribution is as follows `'4'=>5, '1'=>5, '2'=>1, '10'=>8, '9'=>10`.

So ideally the warehouses will be assigned something like this: `WID:4=5, WID:1=5, WID:9=10.`

There are two factors, how close the warehouse is; but also to accomplish the allocation with the least warehouses possible.

---

Any ideas, suggestions how to approach this?

The number of warehouses is dynamic, there could be more or less warehouses. And I'd like to take out as much quantity as possible from the closest warehouse. Thats why I have `$warehouse_rank`.

*PS. I'm not looking for help on how to make the actual order. Just the quantity allocation per warehouse.*

Comment: `I cannot wrap my head around how to go about when the requested quantity is spread out in multiple warehouses.` -- You can't do it by checking a single warehouse.  You have to check all of the warehouses in descending order of proximity (the closest one first), and sum up the quantity of the desired product on hand as you go until you get to the required amount or you run out of warehouses or you get too far away.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes I am doing that with the loop. But thats not enough to check them in descending order of proximity. Because when the requested quantity exists but is spread across multiple warehouses the requested quantity needs to be divided across 2 or more warehouses. Ideally the closest, but also to use the least amount of warehouses possible.

Comment: You'll have to figure out what your rules are first.  You don't need code to do that; write out the rules in plain English first, before you write code to implement them.

Comment: For example, in the case where there is low inventory at near warehouse(s), would you prefer fulfill an order whole from a more distant warehouse as a single shipment (which has shipping cost advantages, and maybe same-lot advantages) , or ship two or more partials from different warehouses?  Once you have your business logic, then you just write up code to handle the cases as per your priorities.

Comment: @ErikEidt One shipment over multiple (or as little shipments as possible). The reason why we added the proximity ranking is because if a warehouse in the same city has the requested quantity they can get them in the same day most of the time. So yes the proximity is important, but also to accomplish the allocation by using as little steps as possible (meaning as few warehouses as possible). I've been busting my head for two days on this, because the variables are too dynamic. Technically an employee could alter the allocation manually but the point is not to have the human factor at all.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a software problem as much as a problem with the requirements. I suggest you take @RobertHarvey's advice and write the rules down in English, either as bullet points or as a flow chart. If you cannot do that, you're wasting your time bashing your head against the code.

Comment: @Borsn, suppose the request in your example was for 10 pieces, would then the proximity prevail (`WID:4=5,WID:1=5`) or the least number of shipments (`WID:9=10`)?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Yes. The least amount of shipments tops proximity. I posted an answer what I did, I'm not happy with it though. Because if the warehouses are ordered in the array differently, it will result in a different order not always the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Look at what you wrote:

> They request 20 pieces.
>
> And the distribution is as follows '4'=>5, '1'=>5, '2'=>1, '10'=>8, '9'=>10.
>   So ideally the warehouses will be assigned something like this: WID:4=5, WID:1=5, WID:9=10.

Why there is no WID:2=1, or for that matter, no WID:10=8? You must be employing some logic here, that makes you say "Getting 1 product from warehouse 2 *costs more* than...". This is your *cost function*.

A brute force approach would be having a function that, given the warehouse layout and the warehouse allocation, determines the cost of the order:

```
function costEstimate(array $wh, array $order) {
    // assert('count($wh) == count($order)');

    $cost = 0;

    // If we proceeded with $order, $wh levels would become
    $whAfter = array_map(function($whStock, $whOrdered) {
        // assert this is not negative
        return $whStock - $whOrdered;
    }, $wh, $order);

    // Number of shipments is number of non-zero requisitions
    $cost += count(array_filter($order)) * COST_PER_SHIPMENT;

    // We do not want to leave a magazine with less than low reorder threshold
    $isBelowThreshold = function($stock) { return $stock < REORDER_THRESHOLD; };
    $reorder_before = count(array_filter($wh, $isBelowThreshold));
    $reorder_after  = count(array_filter($whAfter), $isBelowThreshold));

    $cost += ($reorder_after - $reorder_before) * COST_PER_REORDER;

    // But if we manage to completely empty a warehouse that's good

    $empty_before = count(array_filter($wh));
    $empty_after  = count(array_filter($whAfter));

    $cost -= ($empty_after - $empty_before) * GAIN_PER_EMPTYING;

    // Now add costs per distance
    $idx = 0;
    foreach ($order as $whId => $whNum) {
         $cost += $whNum * $idx * COST_PER_UNIT_PER_DISTANCE;
         $idx++;
    }

    return $cost;
}
```

You can add even more criteria to the cost, or more detailed ones (e.g. the actual distance of the warehouse, or the actual shipping costs, instead of the ranking). Or you can add a gamma function to $idx in the above cycle to privilege closer warehouses rather than farther ones.

Once you have this, your object is to find the combination (the $order vector) that minimizes your cost. You can (remember - this is the *brute force* approach. For large orders or very frequent orders you'll have to research [operations research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research), or at least the various flavors of the Knapsack problem) try all possible order combinations. This rapidly goes out of control:

```
foreach ($combinations as $comb) {
    $test = costEstimate($wh, $comb);
    if ($test < $testSoFar) {
        $best = $comb;
        $test = $testSoFar;
    }
}
```

Depending on your cost function, you may be able to improve the algorithm by "pruning" the unpromising options.

## Another rule

For example you want to empty all the first warehouses, **unless** there is a warehouse that completely satisfies the remaining order. In that case you don't need an explicit cost function:

```
while ($totalOrder) {
    // Test 1. Can we satisfy this entirely?
    foreach ($warehouses as $id => $quantity) {
        if ($quantity >= $totalOrder) {
            $assignment[$id] = $totalOrder;
            $totalOrder = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Test 2. Do we still need to requisition items?
    if ($totalOrder > 0) {
        // Use the first suitable warehouse.
        foreach ($warehouses as $id => $quantity) {
            if ($quantity > 0) {
                $assignment[$id] = $quantity;
                $totalOrder -= $quantity;
                // Stop this cycle and repeat.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above function, in your example, will try to dispatch 20 pcs. No warehouse has 20 pcs, so the first test fails. The first nonempty WH is then 4, which gets assigned 5. The cycle continues and tries to dispatch 15, and cannot, so the warehouses are examined again (array_shift and array_filters here might be your friends), and warehouse 1 is selected to get 5 pcs. The remainder is now 10, and the last warehouse can satisfy this.

The final assignment with *this* algorithm will be WID:4=5, WID:1=5, WID:9=10 and the operation is O(N<sup>2</sup>) in the number of warehouses. You can get it to be O(N log N) by keeping a flipped array sorted by size, but for realistic values of N you needn't bother.

Comment: The logic for `WID:2=1` & `WID:10=8` is because they don't constitute 10. And the first two are the closest according to the `warehouse_rank array`. The rank is determined by the GPS coordinates of the client and the GPS coordinates of the warehouses. It definitely goes out of control, especially because this will be handled by the API itself and it cannot deny an order when the `total_stock` says theres enough. The problem is that I need to assign the products to a warehouse in order for them to be taken out of stock immediately. Can't let them be manually assigned.

Comment: Yes, but you already had assigned 5 to WH5 (remaining with 15) and 5 to WH4 (remaining with 10). You did *not* assign 1 to WH2, to remain with 9, preferring to remain with 10 and satisfy it with farther warehouses. This is absolutely legitimate, and could be another (different) rule: *if a warehouse can fully satisfy the remaining order, use it regardless of distance*.

Comment: Order cost is not important in our case. Because distribution is ours and the order after assigned can be manually reasigned. Right but that would be an endless stream of `if`/`else` statements. And I don't think I can cover all scenarios, would be impossible. What's important is for an assignment to be made 100% of the time.

Comment: @Borsn, when you say "order cost is not important", do you understand what LSerni means with "cost function"? It's a bit confusing because the "cost" there isn't some cost in dollars, but rather an abstract value that determines how viable a certain setup would be. Another name for a cost function is _evaluation function_.

Answer (score 1):

**Input**

- Let `q` be the requested quantity.
- Let `c_i` be the available quantity (capacity) at warehouse `i`.
- Let `d_i` be the distance to warehouse `i`.

**Output**

- Let `x_i` be the quantity allocated to warehouse `i`.

The following approach should give you a fairly good result.

You can first sort your warehouses by distance (closest to furthest).
In that order, allocate as much quantity as possible from the warehouse in question until requested quantity `q` is reached.

With this approach you'll minimize the total quantity-distance.
In mathematical terms, you'll minimize `Sum(x_i * d_i)`.
This would be what user LSerni is referring to as *cost function*.

---

However, from your earlier comments I get the impression that you want to minimize the total distance across warehouses that need to be visited. I'm afraid it is a bit more difficult to find an optimal solution for that type of cost function.

What follows is an approach that uses *Integer Programming* techniques, which are frequently used in the domain of *operations research* (see LSerni's answer). I understand that the following might require quite some background knowledge in mathematical optimization, but it might still be useful to some people.

We can formulate the above approach as a Linear Program (LP).
The constraints are that the total allocated quantity must equal `q` and that each warehouse's allocation can be at most `c_i`.

```
min Sum(x_i * d_i)

s.t. Sum(x_i) = q
     x_i <= c_i
```

In order to minimize *total distance across warehouses that need to be visited*, we'll have to introduce some binary helper variables:

- Let `y_i` denote that some quantity will (`y_i = 1`) or will not (`y_i = 0`) be allocated to warehouse `i`.

In that case, will need to add some 'big M' constraints

```
x_i <= M * y_i
```

where `M` is some large constant. This will make sure that `x_i` can only be 0 whenever `y_i = 0` and that `x_i` can be any positive quantity when `y_i = 1`. Hint: Let `M` be equal to `c_i`.

The problem then becomes a binary problem (where `y_i` is binary).

```
min Sum(y_i * d_i)

s.t. Sum(x_i) = q
     x_i <= c_i 
     x_i <= M * y_i
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I attempted to solve it. It will fill out the warehouses, resulting in 100% of the requested quantity to be allocated.

But it's not well because this is just one way to fill out the order. If the warehouses order was shifted around, we could potentially get a different more efficient result.

```
    $order_draft1 = array();
    $quantity_process = $quantity_requested;

        foreach($breakdown as $whse_id => $quantity){ 

            for($x = $quantity_process; $x >= 0; $x--) {

                if($quantity >= $x AND $quantity_process > 0) { 
                    $quantity_process = $quantity_process - $x;
                        if($quantity==0){ $allocation_percent = 0; } 
                        else { $allocation_percent = ($x / $quantity) * 100;}
                    array_push($order_draft1, array('whse_id'=>$whse_id, 'quantity'=>$x, 'percent'=>$allocation_percent)); 
                    break;
                }


            }

        }
```

If I were to add `arsort($breakdown_process);` before `foreach`, it will make an order starting from the warehouse that has the most stock.

In this case I will need many different "draft" orders for example `$order_draft2 = array();`, `$order_draft3 = array();` and then to choose between them, which I've done.

However it really is not efficient and it doesn't play well when the number of warehouses increases.